# How to fix error "The instance member '_remoteConfigService' can't be accessed in an initializer."

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my first time using remote config. And I can't access it for my videoId. How do I go about it? Thanks

```
static String myVideoId = _remoteConfigService.getEpl01Match;
  

  YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: myVideoId,
    flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
      autoPlay: true,
      mute: false,
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `initState` method to initialize that variable. This method will run only once, when the widget is built the first time. And remember that it can be usued only inside a `StatefulWidget`. The initialization should look like this:

```
static String myVideoId;

@override
void initState(){
super.initState();
myVideoId = _remoteConfigService.getEpl01Match;
}
```